# How to convert a byte array to double array in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a byte array which contains double values. I want to convert It to double array. Is it possible in C#?

Byte array looks like:

```
byte[] bytes; //I receive It from socket

double[] doubles;//I want to extract values to here
```

I created a byte-array in this way (C++):

```
double *d; //Array of doubles
byte * b = (byte *) d; //Array of bytes which i send over socket
```

Comment: A conversion is easy, but an interpretation is not. Which is it you want?

Comment: better language like C++ or JavaScript? For that alone, I'm not answering this.

Comment: How would you do it in JavaScript?

Comment: How are the bytes stored in the array?

Comment: What format is the byte array in? if you have code that created it, post it, whether it was in [tag:C#] or an inferior language like [tag:C++] or [tag:JavaScript]. ;)

Comment: You're asking some weird questions on here...

Comment: What a nonsense! Your choice of programming language depends on the problem you are solving?

Comment: That edit tells us nothing, we need to know how the doubles were converted into a byte array originally.

Comment: Even if your code works, a double or float on one machine may work differently on another. I cant find any links but typically games have physic errors with floats/doubles often which gives it drastically different results.

Answer (score 15):

You can't *convert* an array type; however:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
double[] values = new double[bytes.Length / 8];
for(int i = 0 ; i < values.Length ; i++)
    values[i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, i * 8);
```

or (alterntive):

```
byte[] bytes = ...
double[] values = new double[bytes.Length / 8];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, values, 0, values.Length * 8);
```

should do. You could also do it in `unsafe` code:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
double[] values = new double[bytes.Length / 8];
unsafe
{
    fixed(byte* tmp = bytes)
    fixed(double* dest = values)
    {
        double* source = (double*) tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            dest[i] = source[i];
    }
}
```

not sure I recommend that, though

Comment: What if the data is big-endian?

Comment: @Marc Garvell  i read a text file via File.ReadAllBytes() API and then using for loop i just did doubleArray[i] = byteArray[i]; 
After the loop ends, both the contents of array were same. Yes the size of array was 1000 items.
So when exactly should one use BitConverter? If above solution works.

Comment: @Gabe indeed; then they'll need to handle that ;p

Comment: @zenwalker I'm assuming the data is an IEEE-754 encoded double, so there are 1/8th the doubles are there are bytes. `doubleArray[i] = byteArray[i];` does something rather simpler, and will end up with a lot of doubles holding integer values in the range [0-255]

Comment: @MarcGravell true w.r.t range of a byte, but where else do you see its getting exceeded? Always bytes are 255 limited right?

Comment: @zenwalker I don't understand the question, or what you are trying to describe. Yes c# bytes are unsigned, so [0-255]; but assigning a byte to a double is unlikely to be the right interpretation of data considering it was stored with c++ direct cast.

Comment: @Gabe Then claerly Jon Skeet has a library to do it :-) http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/ look under `MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter`

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, is there some mysterious reason for the not using `bytes.Length` as the last parameter of BlockCopy?

Comment: @Benjol yes; if the original array is incorrectly sized, i.e. it has 20 bytes (2 doubles and a bit), then the new double-array is only length 2. We want to copy 16 bytes, not 20. Copying 20 would case an exception.

Comment: @MarcGravell, yikes, I've still got a long way to go in defensive programming!

Answer (score 9):

I'll add a reference to the super-unsafe code from here [C# unsafe value type array to byte array conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621493/c-sharp-unsafe-value-type-array-to-byte-array-conversions)

Be aware that it's based on an undocumented "feature" of C#, so tomorrow it could die.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct UnionArray
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] Bytes;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public double[] Doubles;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // From bytes to floats - works
    byte[] bytes = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 };
    UnionArray arry = new UnionArray { Bytes = bytes };

    for (int i = 0; i < arry.Bytes.Length / 8; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(arry.Doubles[i]);   
}
```

The only advantage of this method is that it doesn't really "copy" the array, so it's O(1) in space and time over other methods that copy the array that are O(n).

Comment: @MarcGravell Intriguing... Does it uses memory pages sharing? Otherwise it can't be less than O(n)

Comment: MSDN states "As its name suggests, the BlockCopy method copies a block of bytes as a whole, rather than copying one byte at a time. " - however, it is implemented as an `extern`, so I can't tell you what the underlying implementation is. I would *imagine* that it calls down to something like `memcpy`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Then the whole operation is O(n) in space and time (in time because to copy n bytes you have to copy all the n bytes and so you'll have to do n/k operations, where is a constant and is the number of bytes you copy at a time (4 or 8), and in space because you need to allocate a second array of size n bytes). Clearly it's faster than copying them "manually". I had hoped it used one of those "dirty tricks" of copy-on-write :-)