# Borland TDateTime to .NET DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, c++, .net, type-conversion, borland-c++

I have a number-to-date conversion problem similar to

[How to convert a double value to a DateTime in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919641/how-to-convert-a-double-value-to-a-datetime-in-c)

The timedate information I have is pulled as an 8-byte long from a UDP datastream. This is encoded as a double from a TDateTime object in Borland C++, which has compatibility with COM datetime.

I'm decoding this datastream in visual studio C#, and any casting to a DateTime object is coming up with strange dates.

I thought DateTime.FromBinary() might do the trick but this does not decode the time/date correctly either.

The hex values for now() are widely different between the two systems:

```
Borland: 0x 40E4A17C20782C71
C#     : 0x 8E6EA19D6CB5D288
```

These values were taken a few seconds from each other but are clearly different.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to convert this I would appreciate it!

Comment: The question you link to already gives you the exact correct answer: use `DateTime.FromOADate`, not `DateTime.FromBinary`. If you have some question not covered by that, please ask what you're really after.

Comment: Not really: he said he 'has 40880.051388'.  I have 0x40E4A17C20782C71.  What I'm 'really after' is a conversion from what I have to what he had, or or straightup conversion from what I have from the data to a DateTime.

Comment: So you had problems deserialising your binary data as a double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitConverter` ([How to convert a byte array to double array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832120/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-double-array-in-c))  combined with `DateTime.FromOADate` from ([How to convert a double value to a DateTime in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919641/how-to-convert-a-double-value-to-a-datetime-in-c)) is what you are after:

```
var date = DateTime.FromOADate(BitConverter.ToDouble(
    (new byte[]{0x40,0xE4,0xA1,0x7C,0x20,0x78,0x2C,0x71}).Reverse().ToArray(),
  0));
```

Note - depending on how you read bytes you may need to use non-0 offset (if you reading to byte array) and may not need `Reverse` (may depend on endianness between systems). Also depending on the way you read data something like [`BinaryReader.ReadDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.binaryreader.readdouble(v=vs.100).aspx) may be better option to get `double` from incoming binary data.

Comment: I think if you execute this code it will throw an illegal datetime exception (it  did for me).  When I plugged in the 'legitimate' double it returned 12/30/1899 12 AM... endianness didn't seem to matter; it returned the same with and without Reverse().

Comment: @user3235770 I'm quite sure that if I execute the code it would work fine:http://ideone.com/8srPSN