# Casting a managed array to an array of structs without copying

Tags: c#, .net

I have a managed array provided by a third party library. The type of the array does not directly reflect the data stored in the array, but instead it's the data interpreted as integers.

So `int[] data = Lib.GetData();` gives me an integer array, that I would like to cast into an *array* of `DataStructure`, that could look like this.

```
struct DataStructure {
    public int Id;
    public double Value;
}
```

Current I use `Marshal.Copy` (an implementation can been seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311361/copy-array-to-struct-array-as-fast-as-possible-in-c-sharp)), but it seems a bit excessive to copy the entire thing.

Does something like this exists:

```
int[] data = Lib.GetData();
DataStructure[] dataStructs = InterpretAs<DataStructure>(data);
```

where no copying is required, but access to `dataStruct` elements can be done like `dataStruct[1].Id`?

**EDIT 2:**
If I just want a single `DataStructure`, I can use

```
public static T ToStruct<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T something = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    handle.Free();
    return something;
}
```

where no copying is required.

**EDIT:**
The answers possible duplicate are currently about 7 years old, and they consists of either copying the data or implementing a hack.

Comment: Such construct would be UB even in C (where also raw copy is implementation dependant). You can imagine in managed world with a strong type system...

Comment: @kasperhj Are you sure that it causes performance problems? Do you really need to [make it faster](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? Perhaps you can ask third party to provide more strongly typed data from their methods? At worst case you may try `unsafe` code (it should allow to do such things), but you should consider twice before doing so.

Comment: @EugenePodskal No performance problems in my application, but it's a lot of copying simply to change the interpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to convert a float\[\] to a byte\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619041/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-a-float-to-a-byte)

Comment: "No performance problems in my application, ..." - then don't solve problems you don't have. The conversion is probably just a drop in the bucket after that deceptively simple call to GetData().

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree. In my case it's more an aesthetical issue.

Comment: @kasperhj *Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>* and *where no copying is required.* False... *Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>* makes a copy to the structure. The structure could be "blittable" (so a 1:1 copy is enough) or could require some marshaling (conversion).

Comment: @xanatos You're right. Didn't read the docs correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a cheat, but it is an **ugly** **unsafe** **totally unsafe** cheat:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
//[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct DataStructure
{
    public int Id;
    public double Value;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct DataStructureConverter
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int[] IntArray;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DataStructure[] DataStructureArray;
}
```

and then you can convert it without problems:

```
var myarray = new int[8];
myarray[0] = 1;
myarray[3] = 2;
//myarray[4] = 2;

DataStructure[] ds = new DataStructureConverter { IntArray = myarray }.DataStructureArray;

int i1 = ds[0].Id;
int i2 = ds[1].Id;
```

Note that depending on the size of `DataStructure` (if it is 16 bytes or 12 bytes), you have to use `Pack = 4` (if it is 12 bytes) or you don't need anything (see **explanation (1)** later)

I'll add that this technique is undocumented and totally unsafe. It even has a problem: ds.Length isn't the length of the `DataStructure[]` but is the length of the `int[]` (so in the example given it is 8, not 2)

The "technique" is the same I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832260/613130) and originally described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577227/613130).

**explanation (1)**

The `sizeof(double)` is 8 bytes, so `Value` is normally aligned on the 8 bytes boundary, so normally there is a "gap" between `Id` (that has `sizeof(int) == 4`) and `Value` of 4 bytes. So normally `sizeof(DataStructure) == 16`. Depending on how the DataStructure is built, there could not be this gap, so the `Pack = 4` that forces alignment on the 4 byte boundary.

Comment: While I would be really reluctant to implement this in my production code, it does seem to do the trick. As there seems to be no other way of obtaining the same result, this _is_ the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @kasperhj For this there is a solution... (a solution that should be applied even if you want to use reflection) At the start of the program make some "sanity checks": test that the copy of the structure works as it should. In this way there won't be any "hidden problem". Like a unit test that is executed at start.