# Unsafe.As from byte array to ulong array

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I'm currently looking at porting my [metro hash implementon](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroHash/) to use C#7 features, as several parts might profit from ref locals to improve performance.
The hash does the calculations on a `ulong[4]` array, but the result is a 16 `byte` array. Currently I'm copying the `ulong` array to the result `byte` buffer, but this takes a bit of time.
So i'm wondering if `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` is safe to use here:

```
var result = new byte[16];
ulong[] state = Unsafe.As<byte[], ulong[]>(ref result);
ref var firstState = ref state[0];
ref var secondState = ref state[1];
ulong thirdState = 0;
ulong fourthState = 0;
```

The above code snippet means that I'm using the result buffer also for parts of my state calculations and not only for the final output.

My unit tests are successful and according to benchmarkdotnet skipping the block copy would result in a **20%** performance increase, which is high enough for me to find out if it is correct to use it.

Comment: Welcome here and good first question!

Comment: What you are doing is the old "trick" of casting through a struct (this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/35841815/613130)... If you check the `state.Length` you'll see that it is "wrong".

Comment: Still very interesting library you have found :-)

Comment: Thank you for answer, I know that explicit struct trick but actually didn't make the connection that it's actually the same as Unsafe.As<>.

Comment: @Tornhoof The `Unsafe.As<>` doesn't need that trick, but in the end it does the same thing. It reinterprets what is passed as the parameter to another type. In ILAsm it is very easy: `ldarg.0; ret` :-) Nothing to be done :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In current .NET terms, this would be a good fit for `Span<T>`:

```
Span<byte> result = new byte[16];
Span<ulong> state = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ulong>(result);
```

This enforces lengths etc, while having good JIT behaviour *and* not requiring `unsafe`. You can even `stackalloc` the original buffer (from C# 7.2 onwards):

```
Span<byte> result = stackalloc byte[16];
Span<ulong> state = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ulong>(result);
```

Note that `Span<T>` gets the length change correct; it is also trivial to cast into a `Span<Vector<T>>` if you want to use SIMD for hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing seems fine, just be careful because there's nothing to stop you from doing this:

```
byte[] x = new byte[16];
long[] y = Unsafe.As<byte[], long[]>(ref x);

Console.WriteLine(y.Length); // still 16

for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(y[i]); // reads random memory from your program, could cause crash
```

Comment: re the length problem: `Span<T>` could help here - see my answer

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah that's the safer option, though I believe a touch slower because of the length conversions and such. I haven't benchmarked the difference though. As long as he's careful he might be able to eek a touch more perf out of the way he's doing it now. I'm completely in love the new span/memory/unsafe stuff, it makes me want to go and rewrite everything.

Answer (score 0):

C# supports "fixed buffers", here's the kind of thing we can do:

```
    public unsafe struct Bytes
    {
        public fixed byte bytes[16];
    }
```

then

```
    public unsafe static Bytes Convert (long[] longs)
    {
        fixed (long * longs_ptr = longs)
              return *((Bytes*)(longs_ptr));
    }
```

Try it. (1D arrays of primitive types in C# are always stored as a contiguous block of memory which is why taking the address of the (managed) arrays is fine).

You could also even return the pointer for more speed:

```
    public unsafe static Bytes * Convert (long[] longs)
    {
        fixed (long * longs_ptr = longs)
        return ((Bytes*)(longs_ptr));
    }
```

and manipulate/access the bytes as you want.

```
        var s = Convert(longs);
        var b = s->bytes[0];
```

Comment: "You could also" - no! don't do that; as soon as you leave the `fixed` block, the pointer is unreliable; in reality it will *rarely* move, but: it can (GC); never pass a pointer *outwards* from a `fixed` block (inwards is fine)