# C# StructLayout/FieldOffset and indexing in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, alignment, field

I'm having a bit of a problem using FieldOffset correctly with arrays. The code below is an example where it doesn't work correctly for me:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IndexStruct {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] data;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short[] idx16;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int[] idx32;
}
```

If I for example sets the array named "data" to a serialized byte array and then try to retrieve data as shorts using the "idx16" field the indexing is still aligned as a byte[]. Meaning that idx16[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619041/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-a-float-to-a-byte/619307#619307) fetches the second byte in data, not the second 16bit word (byte 2 and 3). If I do the inverse I index shorts instead of bytes, meaning that the offset alignment is inherited from the source data. My question, is there a way to work around this? I know that I can compensate the index value by multiplying with the size of the element, but is there another way?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619041/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-a-float-to-a-byte/619307#619307) is an answer I found here on StackOverflow, but when trying that code it turned out that it wasn't working properly. Tried it out using a Unit test in VS with the following code without any success:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void SumTest() {
    float[] fArr = {2.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    for (int i = 0; i < fArr.Length; i++) {
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(fArr[i]), 0, sizeof(float));
    }
    byte[] buff = ms.ToArray();
    double expected = 3.5f;
    double actual = Sum(buff);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Re your comment; of course, dividing the index by the size may be preferable to unsafe code ;-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is (from what I can see) that you've unioned the **references** of the arrays - so whichever array gets set last will win. Once there is an array, it is using the indexer (not byte offset) - so the size doesn't matter.

The way to do this "properly" (or improperly, as the case may be) would probably be with unsafe code - taking the pointer to the array - something like:

```
    IndexStruct s = new IndexStruct();
    s.data = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (short* data = s.idx16)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data[0]); // should be 1 (little-endian)
            Console.WriteLine(data[1]); // should be 0
            Console.WriteLine(data[2]); // should be 257
        }
    }
```

Of course, I'm not sure I recommend it - but that seems to achieve what you want?

I also wonder whether you can drop the `struct` completely and just use unsafe access to a `byte[]` directly:

```
    byte[] raw = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* addr = raw)
        {
            short* s = (short*)addr;
            Console.WriteLine(s[0]); // should be 1
            Console.WriteLine(s[1]); // should be 0
            Console.WriteLine(s[2]); // should be 257
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that would work and I have considered using it, but if there are a way to avoid jumping into unsafe code I would prefer it. But your method is good and if all else fails I will use your recommendation.

Comment: @Burre Reinterpret casting managed references if far more problematic that unsafe code. There is no reason to avoid unsafe code if you do low level stuff, but avoiding totally perverting the CLR type system is EVIL. I assume your reinterpret cast leads to undefined behavior and might break in future versions of the CLR.

Comment: @CodeInChaos or, indeed, in WinRT

Answer (score -2):

Your FieldOffset defines where each of your data elements are inside the struct..

By setting them all to 0, you're telling the compiler that they all at position 0.

The second thing I see is you're creating an array of bytes, shorts, and ints.

see: [MSDN StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IndexStruct {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte[16] data;

        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public short idx16;

        [FieldOffset(18)]
        public int idx32;
}
```

Comment: Overlaying them at position 0 is intentional in order to have the three fields point to the same memory area. I was expecting that retrieving the byte values with idx16 would align the bytes as shorts and not as bytes, but this doesn't seem to work and I'm wondering why.