# C# performance - pointer to span in a hot loop

Tags: c#, performance, loops, slice, bitconverter

I'm looking for a faster alternative to [BitConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923846/fast-casting-in-c-sharp-using-bitconverter-can-it-be-any-faster):

But! Inside a "hot loop":

```
//i_k_size = 8 bytes 
while (fs.Read(ba_buf, 0, ba_buf.Length) > 0 && dcm_buf_read_ctr < i_buf_reads)
{
    Span<byte> sp_data = ba_buf.AsSpan();
    for (int i = 0; i < ba_buf.Length; i += i_k_size)
    {
        UInt64 k = BitConverter.ToUInt64(sp_data.Slice(i, i_k_size));
    }
 }
```

My efforts to integrate a pointer with conversion - made performance worse. Can a pointer be used to maki it faster *with* span?

Below is the benchmark: pointer 2 array is 2x faster

Actually I want *this* code to be used instead of BitConverter:

```
public static int l_1gb = 1073741824;
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Stopwatch sw1 = new();
    sw1.Start();
    byte[] k = new byte[8];

    fixed (byte* a2rr = &k[0])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            rnd.NextBytes(k);
            //UInt64 p1 = BitConverter.ToUInt64(k); 
            //time: 10203.824
            //time: 10508.981
            //time: 10246.784
            //time: 10285.889

            //UInt64* uint64ptr = (UInt64*)a2rr;
            //x2 performance !
            UInt64 p2 = *(UInt64*)a2rr;

            //time: 4609.814
            //time: 4588.157
            //time: 4634.494
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"time: {Math.Round(sw1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, 3)}");
}
```

Comment: Is `i_k_size` equal to `sizeof(UInt64)`? (i.e. is it 8?)

Comment: As an aside, the inconsistent bracing, unconventional indentation and unconventional variable names are somewhat distracting - at least for me, and I suspect others may feel the same.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes. i_k_size = 8 bytes

Comment: @JonSkeet applied additional spaces, but SO editor leaves much to be desired.
a) I see no problems in braces.
b) codestyles can be different I think
c) I wish you replied to the point of the question

Comment: Ouch. You discard return value of `fs.Read` (test but not store) so you can't use the correct size at the end if the last read doesn't copy exactly `ba_buf.Length` bytes.

Comment: @madreflection the code presupposes the exact input - so this is intentional

Comment: "I see no problems in braces" - the "brace at end of line" for the `while` loop vs the "brace at start of line" for the `for` loop doesn't seem inconsistent to you? (And as for "I wish you replied to the point of the question" - if my suggestions help to make your question more appealing to 10 other users, isn't that actually more useful?)

Comment: Yes, it "presupposes" it. That's clear. But if you don't get what you expect, you have no error checking so it will silently give you bad data.

Comment: @madreflection I corrected this, but - I think you can spend your time more efficiently :-)

Comment: The loss of efficiency was in the pushback you gave.

Comment: @YuriiPalkovskii, you actually cannot assume that you get exactly as many characters as you request from `Stream.Read` in .Net Core 3+ (breaking change from .Net Framework). You *need* to understand how many characters `Read` returned, and possibly keep calling `Read` until you get all your data (or just use a `BinaryReader` on top of your stream, which guarantees it).

Comment: @madreflection adding eof condition will result in an additional code -
this is a very hot loop - so my architectural choice was _deliberate_ removal of this check.

Comment: I never said to add an EOF condition. You're making far more assumptions that you even know.

Comment: Dear @Blindy this is a closed test-only environment. - So far 4 bln iterations give exactly the requested bytes

Comment: It only needs to fail once, and it *will* fail. It is not theoretical, you will crash on this eventually. This is the very definition of a brittle piece of software.

Comment: How do you know? If `fs.Read` returns more than `0` but less than `ba_buf.Length`, you have no idea because you haven't saved the actual count of bytes read.

Comment: @madreflection - u r right (I checked the func desc). will redo the code.

Comment: Imagine the greater efficiency if you had done that after my *first* comment. And Blindy's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimise this quite a lot by initialising some spans outside the reading loop and then read directly into a `Span<byte>` and access the data via a `Span<ulong>` like so:

```
int buf_bytes = sizeof(ulong) * 1024; // Or whatever buffer size you need.
var ba_buf    = new byte[buf_bytes];
var span_buf  = ba_buf.AsSpan();
var data_span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ulong>(span_buf);

while (true)
{
    int count = fs.Read(span_buf) / sizeof(ulong);

    if (count == 0)
        break;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Do something with data_span[i]

        Console.WriteLine(data_span[i]); // Put your own processing here.
    }
}
```

This avoids memory allocation as much as possible. It terminates the reading loop when it runs out of data, and if the number of bytes returned is not a multiple of `sizeof(ulong)` it ignores the extra bytes.

It will always read all the available data, but if you want to terminate it earlier you can add code to do so.

As an example, consider this code which writes 2,000 ulong values to a file and then reads them back in using the code above:

```
using (var output = File.OpenWrite("x"))
{
    for (ulong i = 0; i < 2000; ++i)
    {
        output.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(i));
    }
}

using var fs = File.OpenRead("x");

int buf_bytes = sizeof(ulong) * 1024; // Or whatever buffer size you need.
var ba_buf    = new byte[buf_bytes];
var span_buf  = ba_buf.AsSpan();
var data_span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ulong>(span_buf);

while (true)
{
    int count = fs.Read(span_buf) / sizeof(ulong);

    if (count == 0)
        break;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Do something with data_span[i]

        Console.WriteLine(data_span[i]); // Put your own processing here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry - at first, I've missed the most important point in your code -
data_span + MemoryMarshal.Cast

I've tested and bm-ed your approach - and it is so far the _most_ performant

bm on 2147483648 iterations:

1. my code with BitConverter = 192 seconds
2. foreach(var value in MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ulong>(ba_buf)) = 187 seconds
3. MemoryMarshal.Cast + outer buffers spans (your code) 183 seconds

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `ba_buf` is a `byte[]`, a very easy and efficient way to run your loop is as such:

```
foreach(var value in MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ulong>(ba_buf))
   // work with value here
```

If you need to finesse the buffer (for example, to cut off parts of it), use `AsSpan(start, count)` on it first.

Comment: 4 seconds faster (my test setup) than BitConverter.ToUInt64 for 1073741824 conversions.
Still - I'm not sure if this faster than pointer-span (if possible)

Comment: I've added a BM code to support my oppinion.

Comment: Don't need opinions, you can [check the code directly](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgCUBXAOwwEt8YLAJI8YUCAAcAymIBuvMDFwBuGjWIBmJqQYBhBjQDeNBqaZaOAGwhcA5gwCyACjYxsAEwDyXSwE8pEthcADzAvhgwAHwM7tgY2ACUJmbG1GbpDLLYUAy4HPgMALwMdACqADKqaRmmAGbQbmAAFk5ZOVmWHDAMvFyOMPjQvg7ZuE3Yliy6eBih4TBoDFY2tpFOsfEJSdU16XkFANTFHV1Vu0wA7Ln5Z2YAvjR3QA==). This is as fast as it gets. Any other performance problems come from questionable decisions like using streams for very large files, especially with tiny reads.

Comment: whoa! online disasm is fantastic! Never seen that before! Thanks for the link!