# How to convert from UInt32 array to byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288897/how-do-i-convert-byte-array-to-uint32-array) question only vise versa. For now I got this:

```
UInt32[] target;

byte[] decoded = new byte[target.Length * 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(target, 0, decoded, 0, target.Length);
```

And this doesn't work, I get array filled with `0x00`.

Comment: It would be wrong even if it had worked. `decoded` is only half the size it should be (an `uint` is 4 bytes, so the factor must be 4). And the last parameter to `BlockCopy` is a `byte` count, not an `uint`-count.

Comment: One way can be by defining a structure using Explicit Layout.

Following post may be helpful:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60150e7b-665a-49a2-8e2e-2097986142f3/c-equivalent-to-c-union?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Which endianness? `BlockCopy` uses native endianness, which is rarely the desired behavior in my experience.

Comment: There are two weird points here: 1) Why `* 2` not `* 4`? `UInt32` is a 4 byte integer. 2) The length parameter is in bytes. So you need to use `decoded.Length`

Comment: @SunnyAgrawal: That's overkill because he doesn't have a structure. Just a `UInt32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend something like the following:

```
UInt32[] target;

//Assignments

byte[] decoded = new byte[target.Length * sizeof(uint)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(target, 0, decoded, 0, decoded.Length);
```

See code:

```
uint[] target = new uint[] { 1, 2, 3 };

//Assignments

byte[] decoded = new byte[target.Length * sizeof(uint)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(target, 0, decoded, 0, decoded.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < decoded.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(decoded[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Also see:

- [Size of values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)
- [Int Array to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896680/int-array-to-byte-array)
- [BlockCopy MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1184xdy4.aspx) method for converting a `unit` to `byte`

Comment: The only to `BitConverter.GetBytes()` is that if you have a large array of `UInt32s`, and you need to convert the entire thing into an array of `Bytes`... then you end up allocating quite a bit of `byte[4]s` and have to add them to your resulting array... It can actually end up being a bit slow.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
UInt32[] target = new UInt32[]{1,2,3}; 
  byte[] decoded = new byte[target.Length * sizeof(UInt32)];
  Buffer.BlockCopy(target, 0, decoded, 0, target.Length*sizeof(UInt32));

    foreach(byte b in decoded)     
    {
        Console.WriteLine( b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiple by `4` to create your `byte` array, since `UInt32` is 4 bytes (32 bit). But use `BitConverter` and fill a list of `byte` and late you can create an array out of it if you need.

```
UInt32[] target = new UInt32[] { 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] decoded = new byte[target.Length * 4]; //not required now
List<byte> listOfBytes = new List<byte>();
foreach (var item in target)
{
    listOfBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(item));   
}
```

If you need array then:

```
byte[] decoded = listOfBytes.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few errors:

```
UInt32[] target = new uint[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// Error 1:
// You had 2 instead of 4.  Each UInt32 is actually 4 bytes.
byte[] decoded = new byte[target.Length * 4];

// Error 2:
Buffer.BlockCopy(
  src: target, 
  srcOffset: 0, 
  dst: decoded,
  dstOffset: 0, 
  count: decoded.Length // You had target.Length. You want the length in bytes.
);
```

This should yield what you're expecting.