# Cast float to int without ANY conversion?

Tags: c#, casting, bit-manipulation

I am writing various types to a byte stream by manually casting and shifting values. I have found this to be more than three times faster than using BitConverter or BinaryWriter.

My problem is with floats. I need to cast them to ints in order to perform shift operations on them, but any cast to int will cause an implicit conversion with truncation, etc. I want the keep the exact binary representation the same. Is this possible?

eg. I want to be able to do similar to:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
float myFloat = 32.2;

//following won't compile as can't shift floats.
bytes [0] = (byte)myFloat;
bytes [1] = (byte)(myFloat >> 8);
bytes [2] = (byte)(myFloat >> 16);
bytes [3] = (byte)(myFloat >> 24);
```

Comment: its interesting that you don't ask how to cast float to byte[] without any conversion

Comment: Because as far as I'm aware there's no way to do so without unsafe code. That's why I'm shifting myself. I have a nasty feeling floats aren't going to be possible though. :-/

Comment: is this thread of any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619041/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-a-float-to-a-byte

Comment: would you show your sample good cast?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Just replace the float above with int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float myFloat = 0.124112f;
float[] floats = new[] { myFloat };
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(floats, 0, bytes, 0, 4);
```

?

**EDIT:** compared to `DoubleToInt64Bits` its slower though like 4x times on my machine, which makes sense given its array nature and inevitable overhead when compared to extreme simplicity of `DoubleToInt64Bits` implementation.

Comment: Although this is slow, +1 for BlockCopy which I didn't know about.

Comment: actually if you are applying your code to multiple floats we would need to compare performance of whole operation not single conversion, theres a chance it could be better I am thinking.

Comment: Unfortunately not just floats. Actually array of structs to be streamed.

Answer (score 15):

The following does not require unsafe code and is proved to work (I used it for years across various .NET versions):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct FloatAndUIntUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint  UInt32Bits;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float FloatValue;
}


FloatAndUIntUnion f2i = default(FloatAndUIntUnion);
f2i.FloatValue = aFloat;    // write as float
uint i = f2i.UInt32Bits;    // read back as int
```

Note that the float→int direction can be simpler:

```
int i = aFloat.GetHashCode();
```

However, it is much more obscure because not documented
(as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.gethashcode.aspx)), although confirmed by [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3c3fde60-1b4a-449f-afdc-fe5bba8fece3).
(That is, the behaviour was the same in 2006 as now in 2013,
and I see no reason to change it in the future — but it may happen, 
and I'm unsure whether it would qualify as a backward-incompatible 
change or not.)

Comment: Technically you shouldn't rely on the behaviour - but as homay2 says, I doubt it will change. Maybe protect your code with a unit test carrying some explanatory comments?

Comment: This approach is also used by Microsoft in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, as seen on Roslyn Reference Source: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/RealParser.cs,768

Comment: Also, there's a PR out for `BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits`: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4673

Answer (score 6):

Can you use `double` instead of `float`?

```
double doubleValue = 32.2;
long setofBits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(doubleValue);
```

**EDIT:** Answer to comment

I believe there is no overhead using [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx), using Reflector we can see that it's implementation is pretty simple:

```
public static unsafe long DoubleToInt64Bits(double value)
{
    return *(((long*) &value));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the whole point of me doing this is to avoid the overhead of BitConverter.

Comment: Interesting! However my results clearly show a > 3x speed up by hand shifting, but this is in a very tight loop. I suspect the temporary byte[] arrays being returned from Bitconverter are causing the issue.

Comment: How you able to measure such a fast operation? have you tried to loop ~1M times the convert/shift operation?

Comment: I'm looping 250,000,000 times. I'm aware that such tests are not exact by any means but the test is very similar to the production code so such an obvious speed difference bares investigation.

Comment: How you measure time? Are you using `Stopwatch`?

Comment: Yup, using StopWatch. As I said, I suspect the temporary arrays are causing GC collections.