# C# - Fastest way to convert an int and put it in a byte array with an offset

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unsafe

I'm writing custom byte stream and I want the most the write/read methods that works the fastest way possible. This is my current implementation of the write and read methods for int32:

```
    public void write(int value)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            bytes[index++] = (byte)(value);
            bytes[index++] = (byte)(value >> 8);
            bytes[index++] = (byte)(value >> 16);
            bytes[index++] = (byte)(value >> 24);
        }
    }

    public int readInt()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return bytes[index++] |
                (bytes[index++] << 8) |
                (bytes[index++] << 16) |
                (bytes[index++] << 24);
        }
    }
```

But what I really want is to do is cast the "`int`" into a byte pointer (or something like that) and copy the memory into the "`bytes`" array with the given "`index`" as the `offset`. Is it even possible in `C#`?

The goal is to:

Avoid creating new arrays.

Avoid loops.

Avoid multiple assignment of the "`index`" variable.

Reduce the number of instructions.

Comment: note that MSFT BinaryWriter does it how you do it in yr question. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,279

Comment: have a look at the various answer of _float[] to byte[]_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619041

Comment: Have you looked at BitConverter? Also, do you care about endianness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* pbytes = &bytes[index])
    {
        *(int*)pbytes = value;
        value = *(int*)pbytes;
    }
}
```

But be careful with possible array index overflow.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I did mess a bit with unsafe scope, but didn't really know much about it. The fixed keyword only "tags" the memory so it can't be moved? Or is it copied to a safe place?

Comment: Another thing, does C# guarantees the endianness on every machine?

Comment: Yep, it just prevents array from to be moved during garbage collection - doesn't copy anywhere.

Endianness depends on target platform architecture - see [BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Doesn't fixed keyword have a performance cost? E.g. cost of pinning the pointer?

Comment: better solution in safe context: 
Unsafe.As<byte, int>(ref bytes[index]) = value;

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very fast, but you can speed it even more (almost 2x faster) with the following change:

```
bytes[index] = (byte)(value);
bytes[index+1] = (byte)(value >> 8);
bytes[index+2] = (byte)(value >> 16);
bytes[index+3] = (byte)(value >> 24);
index = index + 4;
```