# What's the fastest way to convert a float[] to byte[]?

Tags: c#, performance, casting, type-conversion

OpenCV uses floats to store SIFT descriptors, where actually it is integer values from 0 to 255.
I am using OpenCvSharp, which is a C# wrapper for OpenCV and I would like to convert the float-based descriptors to byte[] because it takes only 1/4 of the space.
Before I realized that, I was converting the float[]  to byte[] like this to store the descriptors in a database:

```
float[] floatDescriptor = ...;
byte[] byteDescriptor = new byte[floatDescriptor.Length * sizeof(float)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(floatDescriptor, 0, byteDescriptor, 0, byteDescriptor.Length);
```

This was very fast, because I could copy the whole float array without any transformation into a byte array. But it takes 4 times more space than this:

```
float[] floatDescriptor = ...;
byte[] byteDescriptor = new byte[floatDescriptor.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < floatDescriptor.Length; ++i)
{
    byteDescriptor [i] = (byte)floatDescriptor[i];
}
```

But this is a lot slower. Is there a faster way to do it?

**Edit**

I am aware of the fact, that two different things are happening there. I'm just wondering if there is some kind of faster way for batch processing casts in arrays. Like `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is faster than `BitConverter.GetBytes(float)` for every float in an array.

Comment: Linq is not faster than for loops but the following does work : byte[] bytes = (new float[] { 1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F }).SelectMany(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();

Comment: In the first code block you didnt parse to a smaller type... therfore it was just copying the data from one place to another. In the second codeblock you parse the type from a float to a byte therefore it is natural that this procedure takes longer. I dont think that there is a faster way to archieve this than the one you mentioned.

Comment: You want to cast `float[]` to `int[]`, but your first code is not _casting_ `float` to `byte`, it just strore each `float` in 4 `byte`

Comment: @NathanielWalser  yes, I am aware of that. I am not expecting to get the same speed and I'm also kind of expecting, that there is no faster way. But maybe there is one I don't know of, so I thought I'd better ask.

Comment: @vasily.sib same answer as above. I just wanted to be clear about the fact that I didn't want a byte representation of a float. But I was wondering if there was some kind of batch processing for that kind of task, which might be faster than my solution.

Comment: Is this speed difference really important? I mean, for small arrays it won't make any appreciable difference, only if we're talking about hundreads of MBs.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619041/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-convert-a-float-to-a-byte ?

Comment: @CaiusJard the suggested answer for the question you posted is exactly what I did before. But this just returns a byte representation of floats. It doesn't actually cast every single float to a single byte.

Comment: @Alejandro it's in the magnitude of GB. Actually, one of the reasons why I am looking for an improvement is the limitation of byte[] to a size of Int32.MaxValue. I can store 4 times more information in the same byte array, if I convert the floats to bytes instead of using a byte representation of a float.

Comment: "Store the descriptors in a database" - is the float-byte conversion really the slowest part of the process?

Comment: I think you need to add more detail about what you do with the bytes after conversion