# Parsing a List<float> in byte[] and copying it in other array without allocating memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, deep-copy, unsafe

I have a class that contains two List of the same size that I need to convert to byte[] and copy them to another array.

Actually I use this code:

```
var lenght = MyObject.firstList[i].Count;
for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.firstList.Count; i++)
{
      BitConverter.GetBytes(MyObject.firstList[i]).CopyTo(bytes, i * sizeof(float));
      BitConverter.GetBytes(MyObject.secondList[i]).CopyTo(bytes, i * sizeof(float) + lenght * sizeof(float));
}
```

The problem of this code is that it always allocates a lot of memory causing the ** GC ** to intervene.

How can I optimize the code without making excessive memory allocations.
Is there an optimal solution using ***unsafe*** or ***IntPtr*** or ***Span***?

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577253/14619678) but the error appears

> **System.AccessViolationException**: 'Attempted to read or write protected
> memory. This is often an indication that other memory

PREMISE:

- I cant substitute List with a float[]

Comment: Where in your code do you use List<T>? Your code example also does not make sense as-is, as it is not valid C#. The condition in the for loop says `class.firstList.Lenght` is being an integer field/property, but then in the loop body you use an indexer on `class.firstList.Lenght` as if it were some indexable collection or something. And then `Lenght`, despite its misspelling strongly suggests you are using arrays, and not List<T>. How can we help with your quite specific problem if the code you present to us doesn't even make sense...?

Comment: i just changed code. Can you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=net-6.0), as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/619164/12342238) to the question you refereed to.

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(myFloatArray, 0, myByteArray, 0 , myFloatArray.Length * sizeof(float));
```

There is also [Marshal.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=net-6.0) for copying from/to pointers.

In newer .Net versions there is also [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0) that can be used as a kind of safe pointer to data, that allow casting of types.